# Powershell listing highest number in a file from for each loop

Tags: arrays, powershell

The file I use as an array has a list of numbers and from those numbers I am trying to get the largest to display by only using a `foreach` loop.

My current code checks each item in the array and compares it to the current known largest value (initially set to 0) and then changes the `$largest` value if the number in the array is larger then the current `$largest` value.

```
$largest = 0
$TheFile = Get-Content -path .\number.txt

foreach ($number in $TheFile) {
    if ($number -gt $largest) {
        $largest = $number
    }
}

Write-Host $largest
```

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the logic. But there is a potential failure point if you add anything other than integers in the file. Why do you think this does not work for you? Are you running into errors or wrong outputs?

Comment: I think I am replying to this correctly I'm unsure as I'm somewhat new. I keep getting the first number in the file but that number is not the largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to try your code on my machine and surprisingly, it ran into the same problem you did. I am running PS 5.0, not that it is important, because the answer lies in how PowerShell behaves.

I was debugging this line `$number -gt $largest` trying to look for its data type.

```
$number.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

This made me realize that Powershell does not treat `$number` as an `Integer/Double` but a `string` and that is why the `-gt` operation behaves abnormally. I suppose that is so because the source was read using `Get-Content` which assumes that the input is string.

Simply type casting the `$number` should fix this as this tells PowerShell how to treat this object as. For example, you could use `[Int]$number` or `[Double]$number` (In case you want to account for Floating points).

So your Code now becomes:

```
$largest = 0
$TheFile = Get-Content -path .\num.txt
foreach ($number in $TheFile)
{
    if ([Double]$number -gt $largest)
    {
        $largest = $number
    }
}
Write-Host $largest
```

Comment: Thank u! The [int] fixed it! Much appreciated. Mucho gracias

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$TheFile = Get-Content -path .\number.txt
$TheFile | measure -Maximum
```

PowerShell has a `Measure-Object` cmdlet which helps you to measure maximum, minimum, average, Sum etc. for an array of numbers. Refer this [link](https://ss64.com/ps/measure-object.html).

By the way your above logic is working fine for me. I don't see any error. One thing which you can do is set the absolute path here

```
$TheFile = Get-Content -path \\AbsolutePathOfTheTextFile\number.txt
```

Comment: I wish I could do this using measure object unfortunately we all decided that wasn't allowed so we could learn more about the for each loop. I will give the absolute path a shot in the morning but for now I am going to sleep. I will let you know how it goes!